# i have a question about to select the last line of the RichTextBox

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a Question to select the last line of the RichTextBox 
When i click the Button1 it will show the last line in the Messagebox

I tried a lot of codes by it only select the index of the lines 
i need your help

I want the output like

these are the lines i write in the RichTextBox

1.hello

2.world

3.welcome

when i click the button1 it will show the last line in messagebox

3.welcome   // it will appears in the message box

Comment: `I tried a lot of codes by it only select the index of the lines` Show that code. You just need to read all text till the and from the index.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, Finally i got the solution It Really works 
 MessageBox.Show(RichTextBox1.Lines(RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, considering  RichTextBox1 as your RichTextBox name

```
MessageBox.Show(RichTextBox1.Lines(RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1))
```

Comment: The User had put both  VB and C# as Tag..c# is already answered ..Thats why vb given...thanks for downvoting

Comment: Iam working with vb.net for 10 years and using messagebox.

Comment: @preciousbetine : Not true. _**VB6**_ uses `MsgBox()`, and the only reason it still exists in VB.NET is for _backwards compatibility_. The [`MessageBox` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox) is shared between all .NET languages and has existed since **2003**, making the `MsgBox()` function obsolete as of then (that's 16 years ago!). Thus it should _**not**_ be used in today's code.

Comment: @preciousbetine : Most functions in the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic?view=netframework-4.7.2) (check the docs for each class) only exist for backwards compatibility, so one should try not to use them these days since .NET's own methods are much more well-coded and better designed to work with OOP.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(RichTextBox.Lines[RichTextBox.Lines.Length -1]);
```

Comment: Also consider `LastOrDefault`.

Comment: Huh?  `MessageBox.Show()` **is** VB.NET.  `MsgBox` is VB6!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Messagebox.Show(RTB1.ToString().Split(Constants.vbNewLine).LastOrDefualt.ToString());
```

Comment: Error 1 'Split' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox'.

Comment: Sorry use rtb1.tostring().split instead